# IF else statement not returning dataframe in R shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have the following dataframe

```
          DF<-data.frame("variable"<-c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"),
           "estimatesum"<-c(10,3,1,2))
           names(DF)<-c("variable", "estimatesum")

      DF2<-  data.frame("Variable"<-c("New", "Phone", "get", "Buy", "Sim", 
     "Card"), "estimatesum"<-c(1:6))
```

The total base of customers is 10000

```
   TotalBase<-10000
```

I have written the following code in R for thr UI and server.

```
   ui<- fluidPage(
   textInput("message", label = "message",placeholder = 
   "'"),actionButton("do", "Click Me"),textInput("size", label = "size", 
   placeholder = ':'),dateInput("Date",label = "Date"),
   mainPanel(plotOutput("Plot1"),verbatimTextOutput("Output1")))






  server <- function(input, output) {output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
   set.seed(1234)
   wordcloud(words = DF2$variable, freq = DF2$estimatesum, min.freq = 1,
   max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, 
   "Dark2"))})
    text2 <- reactive({{csize<-input$size
    csize<-as.numeric(csize)
    if(csize<=quantile(TotalBase,0.25)) 
    {Out2=DF[DF$variable=="Q1",]}
    else if((csize>quantile(TotalBase,0.25)) & 
    (csize<=quantile(TotalBase,0.5)))
    {Out2==DF[DF$variable=="Q2",]}
    else if((csize>quantile(TotalBase,0.5)) & 
    (csize<=quantile(TotalBase,0.75)))
    {Out2=DF[DF$variable=="Q3",]}
    else{(Out2=DF[DF$variable=="Q4",])}

    outputtable<-Out2})} 
   output$Output1 <- renderPrint({sum(text2()$estimatesum)})}

     shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am getting the following error repeatedly.

```
    Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4495
    Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    Stack trace (innermost first):
    100: <reactive:text2> [#10]
    89: text2
    88: renderPrint [#24]
    87: func
    86: eval
    85: eval
    84: withVisible
    83: evalVis
    82: utils::capture.output
    81: paste
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: output$Output1
    4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
    2: print.shiny.appobj
    1: <Promise>
```

I am unable to find the error. I have run the loop outside the function. It has yielded results. I request someone to help me. I am simply unable to understand the error

Comment: Please post the ui part to make a standalone example that shows the problem.

Comment: Dear Sir. Have posted the UI. Please take a look

Comment: Your example does not make it clear where, or if, `TotalBase` is defined.

Comment: I have made the edit. Please take a look

Comment: Copied and pasted your code, ran it and got `Error in source("~/.active-rstudio-document") : 
  ~/.active-rstudio-document:37:23: unexpected ')'
36:     
37:     outputtable<-Out2})`. Please fix, and if you could make the indentation reasonable that would also be helpful.

Comment: This line `Out2==DF[DF$variable=="Q2",]` probably should have a single `=`. That may be your problem.

Comment: @Dash2 I have corrected the == and it yields the same output. The indentation seems OK as perv R studio. Will check it though

Comment: The indentation is a mess to read and your code, as written, still will not even run....

Comment: I will edit and share the same again.

Comment: have edited. Please take a look @ dash2

Comment: What is the wordcloud function? Your example will not run without it.

Comment: The wordcloud just outputs the data from DF in the form of a cloud. It treats it as the source and the wordcloud runs. Have checked and the error lies in text2 <- reactive({{csize<-input$size line. This part of the server seems unable to access the code. If One substitutes a random number for csize, we get the function working. Is there a parameter that I have missed. @awchisolm

Comment: Please post all the code needed to run this.